# Bootstrap 4 Carousel how to get controls in slide and responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I'm trying to figure out how to get the controls inside the slide and at the same time make it responsive. I have set that margin left and right to the appropriate pixels to have it at the perfect spot but when I check to see if it is responsive it ends up in different places depending on the resolution.

Here is my code
https://codepen.io/andysaurusrex/pen/roPmOq

HTML

```
  <div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner img {
    margin: auto;
}
/* .carousel-control-prev {
    margin-left: 425px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    margin-right: 425px;
} */
```

Is there anyway to work with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I understand you are trying to make a responsive image slider in Bootsrap 4. Provide more details: should the slider have a *maximum width* or a *maximum height*? Should it be *full-screen*, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.carousel {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

... will do it. Pen: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/JwxJKb